# Can we add an interactive legend to the interactive line chart in Altair?

Tags: legend, linechart, interactive, altair

Goals:

1. On mouseover in the line chart, increase the thickness of the line,
   gray-out all other lines, and gray out all other items in the legend
   as well. See [interactive line chart](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/multiline_highlight.html).
2. On click in the legend, increase the thickness of the line, gray-out all other lines, and gray out all other items in the legend
   as well. See [interactive legend](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/interactive_legend.html).

Can we add an interactive legend to the [interactive line chart](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/multiline_highlight.html) below?

ISSUE: **the line-width does not change with the selection on the legend**.

```
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.stocks()

highlight = alt.selection(type='single', on='mouseover',
                          fields=['symbol'], nearest=True)

selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=['symbol'], bind='legend', on='mouseover')
base = alt.Chart(source).encode(
    x='date:T',
    y='price:Q',
    color='symbol:N',
    tooltip=['symbol']
    
)

points = base.mark_circle().encode(
    opacity=alt.value(0)
).add_selection(
    highlight
).properties(
    width=600
)

lines = base.mark_line().encode(
    opacity=alt.condition(selection, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.2)),
    size=alt.condition(~highlight, alt.value(1), alt.value(3))
).add_selection(selection)

points + lines
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why use two layers ?

```
from vega_datasets import data
import altair as alt

source = data.stocks()

selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=['symbol'], bind='legend')
base = alt.Chart(source).mark_line(point=True).encode(
    x='date:T',
    y='price:Q',
    color='symbol:N',
    tooltip=['symbol'],
    opacity=alt.condition(selection, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.2)),
    size=alt.condition(~selection, alt.value(1), alt.value(3))
).add_selection(
    selection
)

base
```

Output:
[image: Interactive legend highlights a line in Altair]

Comment: seems only your legend is interactive.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `bind='legend'` to the highlight is close to a correct answer; however, this solution creates some odd behavior with zero opacity points in the legend.

```
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.stocks()

highlight = alt.selection(type='single', on='mouseover', fields=['symbol'], nearest=True, bind='legend')

selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=['symbol'], bind='legend', on='mouseover')

base = alt.Chart(source).encode(
    x='date:T',
    y='price:Q',
    color='symbol:N',
    tooltip=['symbol']
    
)

points = base.mark_circle().encode(
    opacity=alt.value(0.01)
).add_selection(
    highlight
).properties(
    width=600
)

lines = base.mark_line().encode(
    opacity=alt.condition(selection, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.2)),
    size=alt.condition(~highlight, alt.value(1), alt.value(3))
).add_selection(selection)

points + lines
```

[image]